# Custom color for LaTeX output in Sphinx documentation package

Tags: colors, latex, python-sphinx

I am trying to customize the color of the LaTeX inline formula when using Sphinx documentation package, and html output.

### The details:

I have a file called `func.rst`, which includes the following line:

```
Let :math:`x_{1}` be a binary variable.
```

which is rendered successfully into LaTeX in the documentation I created with Sphinx.

(I have `'sphinx.ext.imgmath'` listed in `extensions` in `conf.py`)

***My goal is to have `x_{1}` colored in red.***

### Things I tried:

1. Adding the color inside the formula:

   ```
   Let :math:`\color{red}x_{1}` be a binary variable.
   ```

   while also defining

   ```
   latex_elements['preamble'] = '\usepackage{xcolor}'
   ```

   in the `conf.py` file.
2. Trying to define all math output globally with:

   ```
   latex_elements['preamble'] = r'''
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \everymath{\color{red}}
   \everydisplay{\color{red}}
   '''
   ```

Needless to say, both (and many more less promising ideas) failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying over my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432647/4686) on cross-posted question at [tex.sx](http://tex.stackexchange.com):

As you seem to be targeting html with math rendered as PNGs images (or SVGs), the current config value to configure isn't `latex_elements`, but [`imgmath_latex_preamble`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/math.html#confval-imgmath_latex_preamble).

I tested since and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, I am adding here the full solution. (THANKS jfbu!)

1. In `conf.py` I defined `extensions = ['sphinx.ext.imgmath', <some_more_unrelated_stuff>]`
2. Also in `conf.py` I defined

   ```
   imgmath_latex_preamble=r'\usepackage{xcolor}'
   ```

   (EDIT: in ooposed to what I previously wrote,there is no need to define in addition `imgmath_latex="/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-darwin/latex"` thanks jfbu again)
3. In the `.rst` file where I have the latex expression, I have

   ```
   Let :math:`\color{red}x_{1}` be a binary variable.
   ```
4. In the terminal I run

   ```
   make clean html
   ```

   ("make clean" is the sphinx's best friend)

*And its working! wohoo!*

Comment: good to know it works! Do you really need `imgmath_latex="/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-darwin/latex"`  ? this setting is only to pass additional options to the latex binary.

Comment: indeed no need for that :) edited the answer. thanks again!