# How to set color for a single word in sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to emphasis one word, or variable let say, inside a math block in Sphinx. Is there a way doing it?

I tried:

```
.. math::
    .. role:: rubric
        c^2 = a^2 + :rubric:`b^2`
```

And the output just simply didn't work:

[image: snap]

Then I tried taking the role outside of the math block:

```
.. role:: rubric    
    .. math::    
        c^2 = a^2 + :rubric:`b^2`
```

Then the compiler gives me error:

> WARNING: Error in "role" directive:
>
> > no content permitted.

How can I use another color in a math block?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50440108/407651

Answer (score 0):

Math uses LaTex engine, so it is possible to use LaTex markup on Math like:

```
.. math::
    c^2 = a^2 + \color{red} b^2

    c^2 = a^2 + \mathbf{b^2}
```